# Pros and Cons of Having a particular type of data in a Single Forest

Tags: marklogic

We have a MarkLogic application and new data gets added/updated frequently. It is user data and we are supposed to take regular backups of data.

We have a part of data(3 Million records) which is not updated.So, Can we place this data in a separate forest and Will that help me in any way.

We are thinking this in view of Backup and Restore.As taking the daily backups of entire database takes lot of disk space.

What are the pros and cons of having particular type data in single forest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't address your pros & cons question, but MarkLogic 8 offers [incremental backup](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_33714), which could address the disk space concern.

Comment: Hi Dave... We are still on MarkLogic 7.. Will definitely implement Incremental Backups when we are into ML 8.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't want to think about having any piece of data in a “single forest”. MarkLogic is designed to parallelize reads and writes at many levels. Putting data in one forest will subvert that and likely lead to hot spots and/or single points of failure. In general, the best recommendation is to spread forests and replicas as broadly across the cluster as feasible, with multiple master and replicas on each host (minimum three hosts for high availability).

As you and @hunterhacker indicate above, there may be characteristics about your data that you can use to make smarter placement decisions than the built-in rebalancing logic. Isolating “hot” (actively read or updated) and “cold” (infrequently accessed) data can indeed allow you to more efficiently allocate resources in your cluster. I’d advise testing first with conditions approximating real-world conditions, though. Often, I’ve seen users that try to outsmart the default parallelization logic only to end up with a marginally faster/space-efficient end result and significantly more complex operations. In the worse cases, they’ve actually made their inserts or queries slower than if they’d just used the default placement policy.

You should also take a [Tiered Storage](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/tiered-storage). This feature allows an administrator to group forests into different tiers, automatically rebalancing data among them.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the response.

Answer (score 0):

With [MarkMail.org](http://markmail.org), we put the user data into a separate database than the message data. This allows us to do very frequent backups of the user data (which if lost would be unrecoverable) without having the newly loaded messages in the backup (which if lost could be reloaded from the mbox histories we also keep).  It also means the user data that churns a lot gets reclaimed off disk faster than if it was in the larger messages database.  We never need transactional consistency between the data sets so a separate database is fine. There's a bit more application logic required.  We wrote a user-lib library that makes [xdmp:invoke](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke) calls to access the user data.

A separate forest is a bit harder actually than a separate database because if you're using forests you can't use the rebalancing feature, and you can't scale up as easily by expanding your one forest into two.